# analyzing a circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resonance

[image]I am analyzing a converter and I have a problem in solving one of its operating modes. can you please help me? the simplified circuit is below.consider diode D is conducting, it seems that the voltage across the Lr is constant, I can not figure out why.. i thought it is two resonant circuit but it is apparently not, i just want to analyze this operation mode that the switch S1 is conducting and S2 is off; do not consider other modes[image: the simplified circuit]
P.S. the initial conditions: v(Cs)=0, i(Lr)=2Iin, i(Ls)=I0, V(cr)=V1

Comment: what is the voltage across Lr, ~0.7V?? Also Ls, and Lr are shorted under constant current source as is depicted in your diagram. Also there can't be any current flow across the vertical wire just after the current source. Effectively the circuit behaves like as if there are no inductors (shorted).

Comment: That current source is not doing anything as it is shown, it can't be short circuited

Comment: no it is 15V and it is dependent on the former operation modes. the current of Lr is changing linearly. why there can't be any current flow through the vertical line? @niki_t1

Comment: Your circuit is wrong, get a correct one, that will help greatly with understanding. Shouldn't a converter have a switch somewhere?

Comment: of course it has switch, the one that i have shown is one operational mode, the vertical line is a switch that is conducting and Cs is a switch's snubber capacitor @Christian

Comment: Perhaps my wording was wrong. If you put this vertical wire, you are effectively short-circuiting the entire circuit, current will take the least resistive/impedance path.  Perhaps, you can model the entire right half of the circuit from vertical line model it as some impedance, say Z, and check. @ReyhanehEskandari

Comment: the current source is shorted and Vout is blocked by D0.

Comment: When S1 is closed, I_L and I_Ls are changing in opposite direction. So when S1 is open again, I_L and I_Ls must be different and that forces a current step through I_L and I_Ls resulting in infinite voltages across the inductors. This circuit is too strange to be real. Too complicated without lots of other assumptions to be analyzed.

Comment: You need to provide people with enough information that they do not need extra comments and changes to give the full picture. Resonant circuits require switching or AC to be effective so you need to tell users about that. It's understood that "this is one mode" but without initial conditions the answer is 'there is no input energy so there can be no output energy. IF there are 2 resonant circuits they interact so you need to comment on the state they are in when this mode commences. || You effectively sort of maybe have two 'buck converters but I suspect you need a reverse biased diode ...

Comment: ... from Lr_input to ground to handle I_Lr when drive is removed.

Comment: maybe i should have asked the question in another way, i just didn't want to complicate the question. i would add the initial conditions. maybe then someone can help me, i would appreciate it @RussellMcMahon

Comment: You did not comment on my suggestion that you need a "flyback diode" at the left hand end of Lr to ground. At present, when the current through diode D is interupted the voltage on Lr will change from left hand end +ve to left hand end negative. The current in LR CANNOT CHANGE INSTANTANEOUSLY, so here Lr will "ring" to -infinity voltas. In practice it would ring negatively until the energy in Lr is transferred to the stray winding capacitances - typically hundred of volts negative. This is incontrolled and undesignable. Fix this or show some more secret components you haven't told us about.

Comment: Allowing people to peek at a small and simplified part of your circuit is unlikely to get a good result. It is hard to impossible to know what you are doing overall or how overall circuit o[eration affects this mode. || Initial conditions shown are ambiguous and/or partially undefined. Relationship between current s and between voltages are unknown and majorly affect what happened next.

Comment: My comments above (now uneditable) re diode by Lr are probably wrong. BUT knowing more overall is still needed.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here is your circuit:

[image]

This is a mess.  You say this is a "converter", but it's not clear what it's supposed to convert to what.  If it's meant to be a switching DC to DC converter, then it should be immediately obvious the switch is missing.

Another glaringly obvious problem is that Iin is shorted.  The voltage going into this circuit (between left end of Ls and bottom of Cs) is always 0 by definition, and the current source is completely irrelevant.

These two problems really should have been obvious.  It borders on rude to ask others to help with a circuit or schematic this messed up.

Trying to analyze this further is pointless since it doesn't make any sense as is, and the schematic is probably not depicting the real circuit anyway.

Comment: t is a dc-dc converter and it is just one operational mode and i have simplified it. i will change the image as it s confusing. i'd appreciate if you look at it once more @Olin Lathrop

Comment: +1 The answer IS useful despite the downvote. I would not have put it quite this way :-), BUT the answer leads in the right direction.